# Maximal abelian subgroups of the full collineation group $\mathrm{P\Gamma L}_3(q)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, projective-geometry

Is there a convenient list of the maximal abelian subgroups of the projective semilinear group $\mathrm{P\Gamma L}_3(K) \cong \mathrm{PGL}_3(K) \rtimes \mathrm{Gal}(K)$ for $K$ a finite field?

This is related to this previous question about maximal abelian subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_n$: [Maximal abelian subgroup of general linear groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200269/maximal-abelian-subgroup-of-general-linear-groups). My question is easier in that $n = 3$, but harder in that I am mod $K^\times$ and $\rtimes \mathrm{Gal}$, which is irritating enough that it would be good to have a reference if there is one.

Comment: I don't know of an easy reference, sorry. Lots of the elements in $P\Gamma L_3(K)$ have abelian centralizers I think. This is useful because (a) such centralizers must be maximum abelian subgroups; (b) if $g$ is an element with an abelian centralizer, then the only maximum abelian subgroup containing $g$ will be $C_G(g)$. You probably know this but anyway...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it is helpful. Incidentally I have learned that there is a "Dembowski--Piper classification" of large abelian subgroups of collineation groups of projective planes (desarguesian or not).

Comment: Ah, well that sounds just the ticket!